# Proving tautology with coq

Tags: logic, coq

Currently I have to learn Coq and don't know how to deal with an `or` :

As an example, as simple as it is, I don't see how to prove:

```
Theorem T0: x \/ ~x.
```

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me.

For reference I use this [cheat sheet](http://andrej.com/coq/cheatsheet.pdf).

Also an example of a proof I have in mind: Here for double negation:

```
Require Import Classical_Prop.

Parameters x: Prop.

Theorem T7: (~~x) -> x. 
intro H. 
apply NNPP. 
exact H. 
Qed.
```

Comment: `NNPP`'s type is `forall p:Prop, ~ ~ p -> p.`, so it's cheating to use it to prove `T7`. When you import `Classical_Prop` you get `Axiom classic : forall P:Prop, P \/ ~ P.`

Comment: So, `apply classic.` solves your goal for `T0`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot prove it in "vanilla" Coq, because it is based on [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic):

> From a proof-theoretic perspective, intuitionistic logic is a restriction of classical logic in which the *law of excluded middle* and double negation elimination are not valid logical rules.

There are several ways you can deal with a situation like this.

- Introduce the law of excluded middle as an axiom:

  ```
  Axiom excluded_middle : forall P:Prop, P \/ ~ P.
  ```

  There is no more need to prove anything after this point.
- Introduce some axiom equivalent to the law of excluded middle and prove their equivalence. Here is just a few examples.

  - [Double negation elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#Double_negative_elimination) is one such axiom:

    ```
    Axiom dne : forall P:Prop, ~~P -> P.
    ```
  - [Peirce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce's_law) is another example:

    ```
    Axiom peirce : forall P Q:Prop, ((P -> Q) -> P) -> P.
    ```
  - Or use one of the [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

    ```
    Axiom de_morgan_and : forall P Q:Prop, ~(~P /\ ~Q) -> P \/ Q.
    ```

Comment: Thank you a lot so far. I am not familiar with everything you have written, but will check though. I use the coqIde and in fact also got a proof for double negation, I added it to the problem description for more clarity later on. 
I expected there to be an analogous way for the problem given above. Maybe I should have included one example.

Comment: @AntonTrunov you need to add some parenthesis to your `Axiom peirce`: as it stands it is not Peirce's law (and is in fact `trivial` to prove).

Comment: @gallais Thanks for spotting that! Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

As others informed you, your tautology is not a tautology unless you assume classical logic. But since you're doing tautologies on decidable truth values, you could use `bool` instead of `Prop`. Then your tautology holds:

```
Require Import Bool.

Lemma how_about_bool: forall (p : bool), Is_true (p || negb p).
Proof.
  now intros [|].
Qed.
```